# Java. Read, write, separate synch

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety

I am learning multithreading, and I have a little question.
When I am sharing some variable between threads (ArrayList, or something other like double, float), should it be lcoked by the same object in read/write? I mean, when 1 thread is setting variable value, can another read at same time withoud any problems? Or should it be locked by same object, and force thread to wait with reading, until its changed by another thread?

Comment: ArrayList isn't synchronized. So, there will be problems if multiple threads write to it. Also, each thread doesn't guarantee the latest value.

Comment: You can check thread-safe versions of Collections, such as ConcurrentSet, ConcurrentMap or CopyOnWriteArrayList.

Comment: I recommend reading this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html I am sure a lot of upcoming questions of yours will be answered there, too.

Answer (score 1):

All access to shared state must be guarded by the same lock, both reads and writes. A read operation must wait for the write operation to release the lock.

As a special case, if all you would to inside your synchronized blocks amounts to exactly one read or write operation, then you may dispense with the synchronized block and mark the variable as volatile.

Answer (score 0):

Short: It depends.

Longer:
There is many "correct answer" for each different scenarios. (and that makes programming fun)

- Do the value to be read have to be "latest"?
- Do the value to be written have let all reader known?
- Should I take care any race-condition if two threads write?
- Will there be any issue if old/previous value being read?
- What is the correct behaviour?
- Do it really need it to be correct ? (yes, sometime you don't care for good)

tl;dr

For example, not all threaded programming need "always correct"

- sometime you tradeoff correctness with performance (e.g. log or progress counter)
- sometime reading old value is just fine
- sometime you need eventually correct (e.g. in map-reduce, nobody nor synchronized is right until all done)
- in some cases, correct is mandatory for every moment (e.g. your bank account balance)
- in write-once, read-only it doesn't matter.
- sometime threads in groups with complex cases.
- sometime many small, independent lock run faster, but sometime flat global lock is faster
- and many many other possible cases

Here is my suggestion: If you are learning, you should thing "why should I need a lock?" and "why a lock can help in DIFFERENT cases?" (not just the given sample from textbook), "will if fail or what could happen if a lock is missing?"

Answer (score 0):

If all threads are reading, you do not need to synchronize.

If one or more threads are reading and one or more are writing you will need to synchronize somehow. If the collection is small you can use `synchronized`. You can either add a `synchronized` block around the accesses to the collection, `synchronized` the methods that access the collection or use a concurrent threadsafe collection (for example, Vector).

If you have a large collection and you want to allow shared reading but exclusive writing you need to use a `ReadWriteLock`. See here for the JavaDoc and an exact description of what you want with examples:

[ReentrantReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html)

Note that this question is pretty common and there are plenty of similar examples on this site.